# duvida expressão linq, clausula IN

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho a seguinte expressão

```
 retorno = (from ven in context.VendaModel
             select new
               {
                ven.barras,
                ven.data,
                ven.valor
              }).ToList();
```

preciso que seja buscado apenas o que tiver numa lista que será passado por parametro, por exemplo a seguinte lista:

```
string[] filiais = { "11.111.111/0001-11", "11.111.111/0001-12", "11.111.111/0001-15" };
```

preciso que seja retornado todas as vendas dos cnpj da lista. Como ficaria essa expressão ?

classe VendaModel:

```
 [Table("venda")]
public class VendaModel
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id_vendas { get; set; }
    public string cpf { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
    public string hora { get; set; }
    public string barras { get; set; }
    public string valor { get; set; }
    public string qtde { get; set; }
    public int cupom { get; set; }
    public string cnpj_filial { get; set; }
    public string cnpj_matriz { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer um `where` e nele usar o `Contains`

```
string[] filiais = { "11.111.111/0001-11", "11.111.111/0001-12", "11.111.111/0001-15" };
            var retorno = (from ven in context.VendaModel
                           where filiais.Contains(ven.cnpj_filial)
                           select new
                           {
                               ven.barras,
                               ven.data,
                               ven.valor
                           }).ToList();
```

Se você quiser, podes ver o exemplo completo em meu [github](https://github.com/pablotdv/StackOverflow/blob/master/ConsoleApp2/ConsoleApp2/Program.cs).

Comment: Paulo, tentei dessa forma, porem gera essa exception "Objeto deve implementar IConvertible."

Comment: Coloque na pergunta a sua classe VendaModel

Comment: Fiz uma pequena alteração na minha resposta

Comment: Paulo, deu certo, o problema estava no campo hora